# How to set individual thread name in Poco that is visible for debugging in kernel traces/ps/gdb?

Tags: c++, multithreading, poco-libraries

I have recently started programming with threads and came across Poco and its threading resource, while launching a thread from **Poco::ThreadPool::defaultPool().start(*testThread, "HappyThread")** and pass a string "HappyThread" when invoking start method.

After thread is launched and running I issued the ps command to get thread name but it is says "a.out".

```
vipin@VIPIN:~$ ps H -C a.out -o 'pid tid cmd comm'
PID   TID     CMD               COMMAND
14051 14051 ./a.out              a.out
14051 14052 ./a.out              a.out
14051 14053 ./a.out              a.out`
```

Whereas when I use pthread_setname_np(handle, "HappyThread") the ps command output gives the threadname as "HappyThread" as below,

```
vipin@VIPIN:~$ ps H -C a.out -o 'pid tid cmd comm'
PID   TID    CMD                 COMMAND
14051 14051 ./a.out              a.out
14051 14052 ./a.out              HappyThread
14051 14053 ./a.out              a.out`
```

below is my sample code(Not perfect just a lazy code):

### test.cc:

```
#include "test.h"

void TestThread::run() {
    while (1)
    ;
}
```

### test.h:

```
#include <Poco/Runnable.h>

class TestThread: public Poco::Runnable
{
    public:
    void run() override;
};
```

### main.cc:

```
#include "test.h"
#include <Poco/ThreadPool.h>

using Poco::ThreadPool;

int main()

{
    TestThread thread_t;

    ThreadPool::defaultPool().start(thread_t, "HappyThread");
    while (1)
    ;

}
```

As far as I looked into poco documentation, passing a string to start method sets the thread name.
I even tried with Poco Thread class and created a thread and invoked setName method but observing the same behavior

Any suggestions as to why this behavior is happening with Poco, or is there no way a name can be set with Poco methods to reflect in OS will be helpful in understanding this problem and to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this and figured it out by digging into the source code a bit. If you look at the platform implementation for Thread, you'll notice a macro that toggles thread names on/off. in Thread_POSIX.cpp its `POCO_POSIX_DEBUGGER_THREAD_NAMES` and in Thread_WIN32.cpp its `POCO_WIN32_DEBUGGER_THREAD_NAMES`.

So, you just have to build the library with these macros defined for your platform. On OSX, I built using the following commands and I now see the thread names in XCode:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-DPOCO_POSIX_DEBUGGER_THREAD_NAMES" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF
cmake --build . --config Release
```